# Increment based on different table

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, match, vlookup, nested-if

I have a list of items for which I need to fetch various info for and make a series of calculations  in a different table.

So I have two tables, one with the list of items, and another "info table" with the various calculations, currently for the first item only.

But I need to have info tables for each and every item in the list, so instead of manually updating the coordinates what I'd like to do is something like copy and paste the info table for the first item and have the top fields update based on an increment of the item list.

Is there an easy way to do this in google sheets?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you need formula in B4 use:

```
=INDEX(IFNA(VLOOKUP(B4:B; D:E; 2; )))
```

if you want formula in E6 use:

```
=INDEX(IFNA(VLOOKUP(D6; A:B; 2; )))
```

---

### update:

use in column D as many times as you need

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ROW()=6, A$4:B$4, INDIRECT(
 ADDRESS(MAX(IFNA(MATCH(INDIRECT("D6:D"&ROW()-1), A:A, 0)))+1, 1, 4)&":"&
 ADDRESS(MAX(IFNA(MATCH(INDIRECT("D6:D"&ROW()-1), A:A, 0)))+1, 2, 4))))
```

Comment: thanks @player0! 

I'm not sure I understand the code, Vlookup looks for a specific key/item?
the formula I need would be in D6, I get the first element from the list correctly  using =INDEX(IFNA(VLOOKUP(A4, A:B, 1)))

however if I copy/paste the info table down below the first , (in d19) the item used is the one in A17 instead of A2.

Comment: @user289829 your objective is very unclear. can you elaborate more on it? you want to populate D column based on E column searching A:B for reference? or you just vant to populate D:E columns by distributing A:B columns evenly?

Comment: sorry, I'll try again: the table and values contained from D6 to M6  are calculated based on the keyword contained in D6. that keyword is taken from the list in column A. 

I would like to duplicate or copy and paste the entire table below (like in the pic starting at d19) but the keyword in d19 would be the keyword in A5. so i can get the calculations for that ticker, and so on, the 3rd paste would have A6 

then continue for the entirety of the list

Comment: @user289829 can you share a copy of your sheet?

Comment: @user289829 answer updated. see: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1DYMcoyDNlBpoS0gTe4dylSXoTi_gnBwDCi35b23vGis/edit#gid=985095861

Comment: perfect thanks so much! could I take advantage of your kindness and ask you to explain the logic,probably because i'm not familiar with this functions I can't quite understand what's going on here, also as I'll likely need to modify this to have more tables on the side as well so its more of a grid rather than a long column! thanks so much in advance!

Comment: @user289829 IF ROW you paste the formula is row 6 then it will output range A4:B4. if you paste this formula in any other row 7, 8, 10...30... etc. it will take the above range (eg. if you use formula in row 12 it will take the range D6:D11. if you use it in row 20 it will work with range D6:D19, etc) and all inputs in that range will be searched against A column and every match will output the row position. next, we use MAX to get the latest found row because if multiple matches are found the MATCH will output all found rows.

Comment: @user289829 so after we get the last row of found match we add +1 to it and construct an artificial range with `ADDRESS()&":"&ADDRESS()` and convert this string range into valid range with INDIRECT. if you need for example to output 4 columns instead of 2 you change the 2nd address `ADDRESS(MAX(IFNA(MATCH(INDIRECT("D6:D"&ROW()-1), A:A, 0)))+1, 2, 4)` to `ADDRESS(MAX(IFNA(MATCH(INDIRECT("D6:D"&ROW()-1), A:A, 0)))+1, 4, 4)`

Comment: thank you, I'll study that some more! by the way I've noticed it stops working after row A12, it continues to output the same line over and over.

Comment: @user289829 yes, that happens when A column contains duplicates. to counter it you can use: `=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ROW()=6, A$4:B$4, INDIRECT(
 ADDRESS(COUNTA(IFNA(MATCH(INDIRECT("D6:D"&ROW()-1), A:A, 0)))+4, 1, 4)&":"&
 ADDRESS(COUNTA(IFNA(MATCH(INDIRECT("D6:D"&ROW()-1), A:A, 0)))+4, 2, 4))))`